# How to plot F statistics and p-value with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot, how to embedded F-statistics and p-value information below the plot like shown in the following plot
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though this plot was created with `ggstatsplot`, but to the best of my knowledge, there is no mechanism within that package to easily insert a table underneath the plot. I suspect the table was created with a separate package and added later.

If you wanted to recreate the whole thing in a ggplot framework (except displaying an F statistic / ANOVA result), it would be possible, but a little fiddly. Here's a full reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstatsplot)
library(patchwork)

df <- data.frame(Recall = c(rep(8:10 * 10, c(2, 4, 10)),
                            rep(5:10 * 10, c(4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4))),
                 x = rep(c("Expert-defined", "User-defined"), each = 16))

p1 <- ggwithinstats(df, x, Recall, bf.message = FALSE, results.subtitle = FALSE,
                   point.args = list(position = "identity"),
                   centrality.path = FALSE, xlab = "")

dat <- anova(lm(Recall ~ x, df))

p2 <- data.frame(x = 1:5, 
           lab = c("User-\nDefined", "Expert-\nDefined", dat[1, 2],
                   round(dat[1, 4], 2), scales::pvalue(dat[1, 5]))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x, y = 1, label = lab)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 4.5, xmax = 5.5, ymin = 0.5, ymax = 1.5,
           fill = "gray") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(1, 2, 4) - 0.5) +
  geom_text() +
  annotate("text", x = c(3:5, 4), y = c(2, 2, 2, 3), 
           label = c("Sum of Squares", "F statistic",
                     "p value", "ANOVA")) +
  annotate("line", x = c(2.5, 5.5), y = 2.5) +
  theme_void() 

p1 / p2 + patchwork::plot_layout(heights = c(3, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>